# Oracle error code ORA-00913 - IN CLAUSE limitation with more than 65000 values (Used OR condition for every 1k values)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00913

My application team is trying to fetch 85,000 values from a table using a SELECT query that is being built on the fly by their program.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
   WHERE (
        ID IN (00001,00002, ..., 01000)
   OR   ID IN (01001,01002, ..., 02000)
   ...
   OR   ID IN (84001,84002, ..., 85000)
   ));
```

But i am getting an error "ORA-00913 too many values".

If I reduce the in clause to only 65,000 values, I am not getting this error. Is there any limitation of values for the IN CLAUSE (accompanied by OR clause)

Comment: I cannot currently answer the question about limit, but to resolve the issue you may use `where id in (select 1 from dual union all ... <repeat>)` or compare tuples, which allow to overcome 1000 items limit: `where (id, <constant>) in ( (1, <constant>), (2, <constant>), ... <more than 1000 items> )`

Comment: The Oracle documentation states that the expression list of an IN clause can hold “up to 1000 expressions”. What happens if you change to 999 per list?

Comment: Also,if you are trying to pick random test cases, maybe use the SAMPLE clause instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue isn't about `in` lists; it is about a limit on the number of `or`-delimited compound conditions. I believe the limit applies not to `or` specifically, but to any compound conditions using any combination of `or`, `and` and `not`, with or without parentheses. And, importantly, **this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere**, nor acknowledged by anyone at Oracle.

As you clearly know already, there is a limit of 1000 items in an `in` list - and you have worked around that.

The parser expands an `in` condition as a compound, `or`-delimited condition. The limit that applies to you is the one I mentioned already.

The limit is 65,535 "atomic" conditions (put together with `or`, `and`, `not`). It is not difficult to write examples that confirm this.

The better question is **why** (and, of course, how to work around it).

My suspicion: To evaluate such compound conditions, the compiled code must use a stack, which is very likely implemented as an array. The array is indexed by unsigned 16-bit integers (why so small, only Oracle can tell). So the stack size can be no more than 2^16 = 65,536; and actually only one less, because Oracle thinks that array indexes start at 1, not at 0 - so they lose one index value (0).

Workaround: create a temporary table to store your 85,000 values. Note that the idea of using tuples (artificial as it is) allows you to overcome the 1000 values limit for a single `in` list, but it does **not** work around the limit of 65,535 "atomic" conditions in an `or`-delimited compound condition; this limit applies in the most general case, regardless of where the conditions come from originally (`in` lists or anything else).

More information on AskTom - you may want to start at the bottom (my comments, which are the last ones in the threads):

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:10737011707014::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9530196000346534356#9545388800346146842

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:10737011707014::::P11_QUESTION_ID:778625947169#9545394700346458835