# What is the max IN query size we can pass to a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I am looking for the max size that we can pass to a Teradata SELECT query with IN operator.

In ORACLE, it accepts upto 1000 values in the IN Query but in Teradata it accepting more than 5000 values.

Performance issue:

When I execute more than 1000 values in the Teradata SELECT IN query, it is taking around 30 seconds.

Sample query;
Select field1,feld2, field3 from Test where ID IN (1,...1000):

Will it improve the performance if I add more filters in the WHERE clause

Like

Sample query;
Select field1,feld2, field3 from Test where createdDate=some date AND ID IN (1,...1000):

Note: This table has lot of data like last 5 years of data.

Thanks,
Panneer

Comment: Put your values in a table and join to it or use *exists*

Comment: I can't speak for Teradata, but in Oracle using the `IN` clause in this way is a bad practice. It creates massive shared pool cursor memory allocations, spends a considerable amount of time in parse before execution can even begin, and with multiple executions even if bind variables are used due to varying list lengths will not be sharable. This can really mess up the shared pool very quickly. You would be better off inserting the lookup values into a table and then joining to that table in your query.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the number of values in an IN clause, only a limit on the overall size of the query.

Regarding performance, what happens when you try adding extra filters?

Comment: This is not true. Oracle has documented 1000 items limit for single-value array: [*You can specify up to 1000 expressions in `expression_list`*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html#GUID-C7961CB3-8F60-47E0-96EB-BDCF5DB1317C). However, it may process up to 65535 items in a tuple array (though it is contradictory to the mentioned documentation article). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69565172/2778710

Comment: @astentx  You probably need to re-read the question. It is asking about Teradata, not Oracle

Comment: My bad, your answer is correct in context of Teradata.